# Applying for UK visa. Can I add one more application to the same envelope?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

Thank you in advance for your help with this matter! I've been struggling with the VFS website for days!

So I created separate applications on the website for me, my husband, and my daughter. Then I was asked to register at VFS. Unfortunately, I registered my daughter's application before I create the family application. As a result, there is no way I can add her to the family "bundle." When I purchased the round-trip courier service, only my husband's and my GWF numbers are there. Can I still use the shipping labels for all three of us? The three of us will go for the biometrics appointments together, and the labels themselves do not show GWFs. Thanks!!

Comment: I am worried. Please help! The receipt of the return label only shows two GWFs, Is it OK to have three applications in the same envelop if we are applying as family?